# How to get number of response of JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

That is jSON request

http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=harry

Follow the link to see the structure of response. How can I get a number of objects in order to create `for loop`?

Comment: by `for cycle` you mean a for loop?

Comment: @Ælex yes, I'll edit

Comment: doesn't `response.Search.length` work?

Comment: your trying to count the number of `Search` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the data (string) in this case:

```
var data = JSON.parse(string);
```

Getting the number of items is:

```
data.length;
```

You can do the same with a file (assuming node.js):

```
require('fs').readFile(JSON.parse(file), 'utf8', function (err, data
{
    if (err) throw err;
    // your data is now parsed
});
```

Then you *iterate* using a for-loop the array you're interested in:

```
for (var prop in data)
{
    // do something with item
    var item = data[prop];
}
```

Iteration nowadays doesn't require the a-priori knowledge of the array length:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
```

That JSON seems to have a `Search` array of objects (see for your self: http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: Do you really mean to use `for each`?

Comment: @FelixKling yes, why not?

Comment: Because that's only supported by Firefox afaik: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in .

Comment: @FelixKling npm/node.js also supports it afaik, albeit with different syntax.

Comment: *"npm/node.js also supports it afaik"* Probably not that syntax since Chrome (V8) doesn't support it. *"albeit with different syntax"* Maybe you mean [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which is part of ES6 (and fine to use). You shouldn't suggest something that is deprecated.

Comment: @FelixKling replaced with for - in :-)

Comment: :) In that case you should probably change the variable name since `item` is not the property name and `data[item]` would be the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.Search.map(function(obj){
   //loop here
});
```

instead of using `for loop`

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with jQuery? Also, `.map` is not for looping. Use `.forEach` instead.

Comment: ops I just leaned that `.map` function isnt a jquery function hence its a raw javascript function.. sorry for that @FelixKling  :3 . also researched about difference between `.map` vs `forEach` but I cant still get why .map isnt for looping xD