# How to call URL sequentially one after another and obtain page source of each URL in Selenium NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to open URLs based on IDs available in Array and Obtain each unique PageSource.

On Executing the below mentioned Code, 5 URL's were opened sequentially but I'm getting Pagesource of only last element

**Eg)** *If body of each url be like*

> {ID: 1, name: "ABC"}

> {ID: 2, name: "CDE"}

> {ID: 3, name: "EFG"}

> {ID: 4, name: "HIJ"}

> {ID: 5, name: "KLM"}

**Result:**

> {ID: 5, name: "KLM"}

> {ID: 5, name: "KLM"}

> {ID: 5, name: "KLM"}

> {ID: 5, name: "KLM"}

> {ID: 5, name: "KLM"}

```
//EmployeeIDs
const EmployeeIDS = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
//URL
const URL = "http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id="

function EmployeeDetails(URL, EmployeeIDs){
    EmployeeIDs.map((ID) => {
        const EmployeeURL = `${URL}ID`;
        driver.get(EmployeeURL)
            .then(() => driver.findElement(By.css("body")).getAttribute("outerHTML")
                .then((result) => console.log(result))
                .catch((error) => console.log(error)))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When i remove your driver part and just execute the map, it doesn't work as you may be expecting. This might be why you're not getting the right data.

This code:

```
const EmployeeIDS = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
const URL = "http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=";

EmployeeIDS.map((ID) => {
    const EmployeeURL = `${URL}ID`;
    console.log(EmployeeURL)
});
```

Returns:

```
[Running] node "c:\Git\JavascriptSelenium\stackoverflow_map.js"
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=ID
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=ID
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=ID
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=ID
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=ID
```

Note that it's not rendering ID. It's navigating the same URL each time - which is why you're getting the same output.

I note that I can't navigate to the url you've provided, so what happens when you go to that page? What data does it return?

A quick modification on this line:

```
const EmployeeURL = `${URL}`+ID;
```

returns this:

```
[Running] node "c:\Git\JavascriptSelenium\stackoverflow_map.js"
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=1
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=2
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=3
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=4
http://example.com/data?source=employee_id&employee_id=5
```

Give it a go and let us know. Try and make sure your map works before navigating.

Also, a really minor point is map isn't designed to be iterated in loop - you're meant to [return it to a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237710/is-map-not-for-looping) and use that.

Comment: Hi sir!.. Thanks for your reply!.. 

On adding question, i made a mistake.
const EmployeeURL = `${URL}ID`;
it should be 
const EmployeeURL = `${URL}${ID}`;

Once again, thanks for your time to go through my question and for your suggestions!..

I solved above mentioned problem, by using *Async/Await* instead of *Promises* sir!..